# Where would I report a case of international financial fraud?

Tags: new-york-state, fraud

If I were confronted with a case of financial fraud in the United States, I would report it to a U.S. law enforcement agency, probably the FBI, or maybe the SEC.

But to whom would I report an instance of fraud by a foreign company that was subsidized by the foreign government? Would it still be the FBI, or should I try an international agency such as OPIC (Overseas Private Investment Corp.), the World Court, or a multilateral agency such as WIPO (World Intellectual Property Organization)--this involved intellectual property?

Or should I try, say, an arm of the Commerce Department, such the International Trade Commission?

One more thing: the country in question has signed a trade treaty with my state, New York. Is it possible that New York State could handle this?